# Difference between the dimensions $years^{-1}$ and, for instance, $\dfrac{animals}{years}$ in mathematical modelling using differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, dimensional-analysis

I am told that an animal population has a natural growth rate of $k \ years^{-1}$ and is harvested at a rate of $a \ \dfrac{animals}{years}$.

Note that the constants $k$ and $a$ are both given as rates but, from a dimensional analysis perspective, they are different. I do not understand why one rate is given in the units $years^{-1}$ and the other is given in $\dfrac{animals}{years}$; indeed, I would have expected the growth rate to also be given in $\dfrac{animals}{years}$, since it is, after all, the *growth rate of animals per year*?

Obviously, this difference matters, since our units must make sense when modelling using differential equations. But I'm having trouble reasoning about this difference; it seems to make no sense when attempting to reason about it intuitively.

Why are the units $years^{-1}$ instead of $\dfrac{animals}{years}$, as they are for the other rate? Doesn't it make sense to have them both as $\dfrac{animals}{years}$, since they are rates?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to help me understand this.

EDIT:

If readers are interested in the specific problem, it is from [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/basic-de-and-separable-equations/MIT18_03SCF11_rec_01s1.pdf) MIT differential equations problem set:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see the difference is to think about the differential equation involved.  If $N$ is the number of animals, then the differential equation will be in terms of $\frac{dN}{dt}$, which has units of animals per year.  This means that every term has to have units of animals per year.  The first term will have $k$, but $k$ by itself has the incorrect units; it has to be multiplied by $N$ to have the correct units.  The second term will simply be $a$ since $a$ already has the same units as the differential term.  For the first term, the rate depends on the population; for the second, the rate is a constant.  So the final differential equation is 
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=kN-a$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is the same reason that angular speed is sometimes measured in $\mathrm{time}^{-1}$ (such as $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$) rather than $\frac{\mathrm{angle}}{\mathrm{time}}$ (such as $\frac{\mathrm{rad}}{\mathrm{s}}$).

It is because you consider some variables (angles, animals...) as dimensionless variables. This is because they are not physical quantities and they can be reduced to a proportionality constant (you measure the quantity 'animals' in the unit 'number of animals').
$$\frac{\mathrm{animals}}{\mathrm{years}}=\frac{1}{\text{total number of animals}}\frac{1 \text{ animal}}{\mathrm{years}}\simeq k \,\mathrm{years}^{-1}$$

It may seem reasonable to show the results in $\frac{\mathrm{animals}}{\mathrm{years}}$, specially is you want to talk about several ratios (like $\frac{\mathrm{predators}}{\mathrm{years}}$ or $\frac{\mathrm{preys}}{\mathrm{years}}$), but notice that all these ratios are comparable between each other (for example, 'predator population grow at a slower rate than prey population') because they have the same physical unit: $\mathrm{years}^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see what you mean. But this then begs the question, why did they use $years^{-1}$ for $k$ and $\dfrac{animals}{years}$ for $a$? If we take what you're saying for granted, then this seems to be an inconsistency, no?

Comment: No, they are not the same.  The dimensions matter here.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the response. I would appreciate it if you would be so kind as to elaborate.